# Bitachon when collecting tzedakah

Tags: tzedakah-charity, travel, faith-bitachon-emunah, chovos-halvavos

In the [Chavos Halevavos](https://www.sefaria.org/Duties_of_the_Heart%2C_Fourth_Treatise_on_Trust%2C_Introduction.30?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) chapter on Bitachon, we are comparing an alchemist to someone who has trust in Hashem. Its writes:

> והשמיני שבעל הכימיה איננו מתעכב בשום מקום מיראתו שמא יתגלה סודו. והבוטח באלהים בבטחה בארצו ובמנוחת נפש במקומו כמו שכתוב (תהלים לז ג) בטח בה׳ ‎‎ועשה טוב שכן ארץ ורעה אמונה, ואמר (תהלים לז כט) צדיקים יירשו ארץ וישכנו לעד עליה.
> (8) The alchemist does not linger in one place too long due to fear that his secret will be discovered. But one who trusts in G-d feels secure in his land, and has peace of mind in his place, as written "Trust in the L-ord and do good; dwell in the land and be nourished by faith" (Tehilim 37:3), and "The righteous shall inherit the land and dwell forever in it" (Tehilim 37:29).

If one who has Bitachon has a security that Hashem will provide in his land. Why do Rabbanim travel to America to collect tzedakah? It sounds like from here that it would be a lack of bitachon.

Comment: They don't mind if their "secret" will be discovered? This 8th point doesn't seem to be dealing with money?

Comment: The point isn't the travel, it's the fear of their loss of income. Someone who trusts in Hashem may have to travel, but he knows his sustenance is assured.

Comment: @shmosel why should he have to travel? It says he will be secure in his land